# Unable to locate PostgreSQL folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I'm in the process of trying to find out or reset my PostgreSQL password, which is unknown to me, but which I need in order to migrate my database from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL.

I was trying to locate the hba_conf file so in the terminal I entered:

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

and I found that the directory I needed to find was:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
```

My problem now is that it is not possible to locate this file because it apparently doesn't exist! When I cd to Library I'm unable to go any further because there is no PostgreSQL folder listed.

This is a bit of a dead end for me as I have no idea why PostgreSQL is not there. PSQL came with my version of Rails, and I updated it. When I type: 'psql -V' in the terminal, the answer is 'psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.3'.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks :-)

---

From the library folder, if I run 'sudo su' then enter ls, I get the following:

```
.localized      Calendars       Dictionaries        Internet Plug-Ins   
Maps            Saved Application State WebKit
Accounts        CallServices        Favorites       Keyboard        
Messages        Screen Savers       com.apple.nsurlsessiond
Address Book Plug-Ins   ColorPickers        FontCollections     
Keyboard Layouts    Metadata        Services        iMovie
Application Scripts Colors          Fonts           KeyboardServices    
Passes          Sharing
Application Support Compositions        GameKit         Keychains       
PreferencePanes     Sounds
Assistant       Containers      Google          LanguageModeling    
Preferences     Spelling
Assistants      Cookies         Group Containers    LaunchAgents        
Printers        Suggestions
Audio           CoreData        IdentityServices    Logs            
PubSub          SyncedPreferences
Caches          CoreFollowUp        Input Methods       Mail            
Safari          Voices
```

and if I enter ps I get this:

```
PID TTY           TIME CMD
359 ttys000    0:00.02 login -pfl robertosullivan /bin/bash -c exec -
la bash /bin/bash
3267 ttys000    0:00.02 sudo su
3269 ttys000    0:00.01 su
3270 ttys000    0:00.00 sh
3271 ttys000    0:00.00 ps
```

---

If I try 'sudo find / -name psql' - I get:

```
find: /dev/fd/Library: No such file or directory
find: /dev/fd/Library: No such file or directory
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3/bin/psql
```

---

When I try 'sudo find /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data -name *.conf' I get:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/pg_ident.conf
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postgresql.auto.conf
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postgresql.conf
```

Comment: list `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data` as sudo user

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to say that I also tried to find this after entering 'sudo su', but the same results

Comment: why you think folder is `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data` then?.. I dont see postgres running in ps output?..

Comment: I was following a post on this website that told me this was the way to find the conf_hba file. I diodn't know about ps until you spoke of it, I am just trying to find my PSQL password.

Comment: But I did stop and restart psql by using 'brew services stop/restart postgresql' - although this renders the same results after ps

Comment: find where you have psql then with `sudo find / -name psql`?..

Comment: That command returns: find: /dev/fd/Library: No such file or directory
find: /dev/fd/Library: No such file or directory
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3/bin/psql

Comment: so you have `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/`?.. or `No such file or directory`?.. not clear with such formatting

Comment: finally please update with result of `sudo find /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data -name *.conf`

Comment: @Vao - That's done

Comment: Try the official [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) instead. Its quite a bit quicker than setting up postgres yourself and gives you a GUI icon to control the server.

Comment: so now you have pg_hba.conf you need to modify in case you cant login passwordless. run `pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data status` to check if db is up. same with start instead of status to start it up, then run `psql` to connect locally

Comment: This command returns the following: pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied :-(

Comment: `sudo su - postgres` then and try again?..

Comment: Okay! Now I get: pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 88)
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/postgres "-D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data"

Comment: then connect to it with `psql` and reset a password

Comment: @Vao - sorry to come back to you so late - I don't know how to connect with psql and reset a password from here. Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The installation procedure creates a user account called postgres that is associated with the default Postgres role. In order to use Postgres, we can log into that account.

You can  run the command you'd like with the postgres account directly with sudo

```
 sudo -u postgres psql
```

This will prompt for the password for the postgres user.

If you don't have the password for this postgres user, follow the below steps:

```
 sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Around the line number 84,85 change that to

```
 # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
 local   all             all              trust
```

then Restart the PostgreSQL service via SUDO command

```
  sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Now You can  run the command to log in to the postgres account directly with sudo

```
    sudo -u postgres psql
```

You will be now entered and will See the Postgresql terminal.Once you have successfully logged into postgres, you can change the password by the command

```
     \password
```

and enter the NEW Password for Postgres default user, After Successfully changing the Password again go to the pg_hba.conf and revert the change to "md5"

Around the line number 84,85 change that now  to

```
 # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
 local   all             all              md5
```

then Restart the PostgreSQL service via SUDO command

```
  sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

now you will be logged in as

```
  psql -U postgres
```

with your new Password.

Please let me know if you have any Issues.

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer. Unfortunately I'm getting stuck on the sudo vim part - this seems to take me to a blank and unresponsive page. I've searched for commands or ways of editing this page but have found nothing so far

Comment: @Robert , you can also edit the pg_hba.conf file using 
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

Comment: In sudo nano I also have a blank file. I have tried to add ' # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
 local   all             all              trust' to this file, though not on lines 84,85 because there are no numbers. When I try exiting nano sudo I get: [ Error writing /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf: No such file or directory ]

Comment: @Robert, after making the necessary changes , use ctl + x to save the file .Then you will be prompted with "save  modified buffer" , press Y  to save the changes

Comment: this is what I have tried - ctrl + x, but I get the above error message

Comment: Hello again Suresh, I was hoping to ask you about the advice you gave me. I have followed all the steps above successfully, with the exception of the last two steps. I find at this point I am unable to restart psql, and every pg_ctl command I'm trying is giving me the same error message: Permission Denied. I am able to open psql with the psql -U postgres command, but not just with psql. It seems that postgres is not fully functional but I can't do anything to change it. Please could you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as we identified your data_dir as `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/` and found configuration files in it, as we identified your postgres cluster is running with `pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 88) /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/postgres "-D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data`, in order to reset your password do:

1. become a postgres user: `sudo su - postgres`
2. login locally with `psql`
3. reset the password with `alter user USERNAME password 'NEW_PASSWORD'`

after that you can connect as that user with `psql -U USERNAME -h localhost` using your new password

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the second stage. If I type psql at this point, I'm prompted for my psql password, which I don't have.

Comment: if it asks for a password a postgres user, change /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
 md5 to peer against the line with local and run `pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data reload` and try again

Comment: I've been trying to edit the pg_pga.conf file in VIM but all I find is a blank file with 'new directory' at the bottom

Comment: do it with sudo user instead

Comment: Do you mean entering: sudo user /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf? I've tried this but I'm prompted for a password that I don't have again.